# Sharepoint List randomly duplicating submitted Item

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer, infopath, custom-lists

I have some weird problem that I encounter while working with Sharepoint custom list. Sometimes created list is duplicating itself. But the workflows of the duplicated item is not running. Anyone having this same issue?

[Duplicated List sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdpeW.png)

Comment: How you create list items that duplicated ? Manually or by some code ? If by some code or workflow then show this code or workflow here to understand why it can be.

Comment: Hi, i dont use any code in this list, i only use workflows. So basically i create manually.

Comment: did you get any solution for this? I'm also getting same issue